# plot doesn't show when using ggvis

Tags: shiny

I have trouble when render plots using ggvis in my Shiny app.

In `ui.R`:

```
 mainPanel(
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("coolplot")))
```

In `server.R`:

```
  output$coolplot <- renderPlot({
if (is.null(filtered())) {
  return()
}
filtered() %>% ggvis(~Alcohol_Content, fill := "#fff8dc") %>% 
  layer_histograms(width = 1, center = 0)
})
```

When I use ggvis, the plot shows in my RStudio viewer pane but not in window (and the plot doesn't show when I push it onto `shinyapps.io`) It works fine if I use ggplot2 instead of ggvis.

Comment: in ui.R you need ggvisOutput() take a loot at http://ggvis.rstudio.com/interactivity.html